# ERROR: mkdir with chown not working in Dockerfile (nginx with php-fpm)

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For version control and security I want to merge two Dockerfiles into one and then create a directory for .sock => running rmdir and chown.
Without rmdir and chown, I can perfectly build the docker if run over port:9000. As soon as I try setting up the directory for .sock, in the dockerfile, the docker build process exits. All Details below. Thanks a ton for any help.

1st Dockerfile half

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.6-1~jessie


RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 \
        && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                                                ca-certificates \
                                                nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \
                                                nginx-module-xslt \
                                                nginx-module-geoip \
                                                nginx-module-image-filter \
                                                nginx-module-perl \
                                                nginx-module-njs \
                                                gettext-base \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
        && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log


EXPOSE 80 443
#CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

2nd Dockerfiel half
[with this PHP code](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/4ea9e241d26b245fa04896a608c73e84522f8689/7.1-rc/fpm/Dockerfile) and the respective files one level above this code.
I don't expose the 9000 port and comment out the CMD.
All is then managed through supervisord.

I build it with help of docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../../builds/nx1116Php71RC6Comp123_J
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image:
      tl_nx1116php71rc6comp123:v1
    #mounts HOST:CONTAINER (the actual server to the container system)
    volumes:
      #nginx
      - ../../data/nxphp/nginx1116/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ../../data/nxphp/nginx1116/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ../../logs/nxphp:/var/log/nginx
      #PHP
      - ../../data/nxphp/php71fpm/etc:/usr/local/etc
#      - ../../logs/nxphp/php71fpm:?????
      #Supervisor
      - ../../data/nxphp/supervisor/supervisor.conf:/etc/supervisor.conf
      - ../../logs/supervisor:/var/log/supervisor
    #foward port HOST:CONTAINER
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

When I run it like that, set up php and nginx confs to work with 9000 all works fine.

**BUT** I want to talk to .sock. There is none, so I need to create a/the directory, where nginx can put it. Thus in my mind I put at the end of my docker file

```
RUN set -xe \
        mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm
        && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm
```

yet that always ends with a building error. and when i exec into the partially build docker image, i cannot find /var/run/php-fpm. I also tried putting it just into /run, but had the same result. Making two RUN commands from it "works" in that way, that I have no error, but the folder still does not exist and then obviously my image quits that it cannot find .sock folder.

&& {            echo '[global]';                 echo 'daemonize = no';          echo;           echo '[www]';           echo 'listen = [::]:9000';       } | tee php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 609c93af398d
Step 22 : RUN set -xe mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm
 ---> Running in de4b7443a82a
+ chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm
chown: cannot access '/var/run/php-fpm': No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm' returned a non-zero code: 1

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors on this line:

```
RUN set -xe \
    mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm
```

The first is that `mkdir` is an arg of set without the `&&` separator. And the second is that `&& chown ...` is treated as a dockerfile command since the previous line ended without an `\`. Here's the corrected syntax:

```
RUN set -xe \
 && mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm \
 && chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php-fpm
```

Comment: THANKS! I can't believe I missed that. I had the backslash (lost it when copying), but I missed the && mkdir. And I was looking at that statement for 2 hours, and just didn't see it. Even tried with `;` and separation ...........grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr. Thanks again!